# Cannot populate FormData using the constructor

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular app i have the following simple form:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login()">
  <div id="container-credentials">
    <input type="text" name="username" formControlName="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" formControlName="password">
  </div>
</form>
```

When i access the values using the `FormGroup` named `loginForm`, it works as expected:

```
login() {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value); // {username: "asd", password: "xyz"}
}
```

But i would like to create a `FormData` object from the values using the `FormData` constructor.

The `FormData` constructor can accept a `HTMLFormElement` parameter as explained in its [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

> An HTML  element — when specified, the `FormData` object will be
>   populated with the form's current keys/values using the name property
>   of each element for the keys and their submitted value for the values.
>   It will also encode file input content.

So i've tried adding an `id` to my form:

```
<form id="myForm" [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login()">
```

And then in `login()`:

```
const myFormElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
const data = new FormData(myFormElement as HTMLFormElement);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {}
```

But the `FormData` is empty in this case.

I've also tried passing the form directly from the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login($event.target)">
```

And then:

```
login(target) {
    console.log('Target: ' + target); // Target: [object HTMLFormElement]
    const data = new FormData(target);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {}
}
```

Still empty.

I've also tried using `@ViewChild` with `ElementRef`, the result is the same.

I know i could add the values one by one using `FormData` methods such as `append()` or `set()`, but i'd like to create `FormData` from more complex structures as well and this would be the easiest way (if it worked).

What am i missing here?

I'd really appreciate any advice.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to check the `FormData` this way as well in all cases:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(formData)) {
  console.log('Key: ' + key);
  console.log('Value: ' + formData[key]);
}
```

I've got no output, which i think also indicates that the `FormData` is indeed empty.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I've tried to iterate through the `FormData` with `Object.keys()`, it's empty. I'm updating my question with this information.

Comment: Sure or it would be better if you provide stackblitz

Comment: try this:
`for (var [key, value] of data.entries()) { 
  console.log(key, value);
}`

Comment: Add this value in formData-> `this.loginForm.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FormData.entries()` which would return you an `iterator` which you can use to go through the data in the form. Note that I have demonstrated my example in vanilla JS.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

```js
function login(){
   var form = document.getElementById("loginForm");
   var data = new FormData(form);
   var formData = {};
   for(var pair of data.entries()) {
       formData[pair[0]] = pair[1]; //To convert to object
   }
   console.log(formData);
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return login()">
  <div id="container-credentials">
    <input type="text" name="username" formControlName="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" formControlName="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Calling `entries()` on the `FormData` results in the following error for me: **Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'**.

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json` what is `target`? is it `es5`? if yes change it to `"target": "es6"`